# Magento Observer - Getting Newsletter Subscribtion from Order Object

Tags: magento, checkout, newsletter, observers

What can I call from an `$observer` object to determine if the guest or customer clicked the subscribe checkbox on checkout? So far I have this:

```
public function collectCustomerData($observer)
{
    $this->observer = $observer;
    $this->_order = $this->observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    $this->_address = $this->_order->getShippingAddress();
    $this->data['first_name'] = $this->_address->getFirstname();
    $this->data['last_name'] = $this->_address->getLastname();
    $this->data['city'] = $this->_address->getCity();
    $this->data['email'] = $this->_order->getCustomerEmail();
}
```

but I need to add `$this->data['is_newsletter']` from either `$this->_order`(Mage_Sales_Model_Order) or `$this->_address`(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Address), or pull in another model that has that information through static factory methods such as Mage::getModel() if I need to

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I had to bring the `newsletter/subscriber` model into the equation. The following code returned either 1 or null:

```
$email = $this->_order->getCustomerEmail();
$isNewsletter = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')
    ->loadByEmail($email)
    ->getSubscriberStatus();
```

Based on that I was able to set the opt in flag appropriately:

```
$this->data['is_newsletter'] = $isNewsletter;
```